# Execute console command in PHP

Tags: php, console, phantomjs

I'm trying to execute a console command when a user clicks an "Export PDF" button. I'm using Phantom JS to generate a PDF output.

If I run the following in my command prompt it all works fine:

```
phantomjs.exe generate_pdf.js http://hidden_link.com/view_printable_proposal/CPpktzdnbwDB test.pdf
```

So, I created a function in my controller, and when you click the Export PDF button it goes to that function:

```
<a href="<?= base_url().'create_pdf/'.$hash ?>"><button type="button" class="btn" style="width: 100%;">Export as PDF</button></a>
```

The whole function I have:

```
public function create_pdf($hash = false)
{

    $output = 'phantomjs.exe generate_pdf.js http://hidden_link.com/view_printable_proposal/CPpktzdnbwDB test.pdf';
    shell_exec($output);
}
```

As you can tell, I've never tried to execute a console command before in any language. Am I even close?

Thanks!

PS: To give you some insight on that console command if your not sure what it's doing - the first bit, phantomjs.exe is calling the .exe application, then "generate_pdf" is a javascript file in the same directory as the .exe app. The 3rd item is my link to the thing I'm trying to turn into a PDF. The final "test.pdf" is simply what to name the PDF after it is exported. Again, everything works perfect through the command prompt to the command I'm trying to run works fine.

By the way, currently when I click the button I just go to a white page and nothing happens.

Comment: You may need to url encode the space in your command. However, the execution environment when executing via web server may not be the same when executing via user shell session.

Comment: I think it's not entering the function either....try to put a form, with just a submit button with "Export" value, and name it "export_test"; then check in your pho file if(isset($_POST['export'])){ create_pdf(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working yesterday, here is the answer:

```
public function create_pdf($hash = false)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $output ="";
    $return_val = 0;
    //echo APPPATH;

    $path_to_js = APPPATH.'/libraries/generate_pdf.js';

    $base_url = $this->config->item("base_url");

    $tmp_location = $this->config->item("tmp_location");

    $output_path = $tmp_location."/".$hash.'.pdf';

    $command = $this->config->item('phantomjs_path').' '.$path_to_js.' '.$base_url.'view_printable_proposal/'.$hash.' '.$output_path;
//  $command = '/usr/bin/ls /';

    exec($command, $output, $return_val);

    if($return_val) {
        echo "Error";
        echo $return_val;
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    else {
            $data = file_get_contents($output_path);
            force_download($hash.".pdf", $data);
            unlink($output_path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is remotely involved, but if you can verify that you are hitting your function, and shell_exec is attempting to execute, you may want to verify that phantomjs.exe is available from your web server's user's PATH.  Easiest way to see if this is an issue is probably to just use the full path of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Phantomjs can't be accessed through a non-root user like server user www-data directly as it gives Permission denied error. In order to run it through the php file you will need to do a workaround. the complete solution is here http://cisight.com/run-latest-phantomjs-with-shell_exec-php-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php
Instead of using some external application, use a PECL extension. This could be a problem if your host haven't installed the extension. But then again, you are trying to execute some shell command, so you probably have the necessary control of the webserver.